# how to make constant function in Ada?

Tags: arm, ada

I'm working on an ARM system that has bit banding. This involves computing addresses, and defining object whose addresses are computed. I'd like to define a function to compute those addresses, but I can't really find my way around the language. The best I could come up with is a generic package where the parameters are input to the computation. One of the problems is that I have to (well, maybe you can correct me, I'm a beginner) use it in 2 separated statements, one for defining the instantiated package and one for using it. So is there a less convoluted way to do it? and le less verbose too? I feel like I'm smearing my files with unnecessary cruft.

here is what I have come with with so far:

```
generic
    register_base : Natural;
    bit_number : Natural;
package PeriphBitBand is
    address: constant System.Address := System'To_Address(Peripheral_Alias_Base+ (register_base - Peripheral_Base)*32 + bit_number*4);
end PeriphBitBand;
```

and one usage :

```
generic
    RCC_ENABLE_REGISTER_Base : Natural;
    RCCBit : Natural;
package STM32F4.GenericPeripheral is
    RCC_ENABLE   : Boolean with Atomic, size=>32;
private
    package add is new PeriphBitBand(RCC_ENABLE_REGISTER_Base, RCCBit);
    for RCC_ENABLE'Address use add.address;
end STM32F4.GenericPeripheral;
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a `function` that does what you want?  Offhand, I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work, but if you tried something and got an error at compile-time, please post that.  That would make it easier for us to tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from where you are, the simplest way is probably a function:

```
with Whatever_Declares_Addresses;

function reg_bit_to_address (register_base,bit_number : Natural) 
   return System.Address is
begin
   return System'To_Address (Whatever_Declares_Addresses.Peripheral_Alias_Base + 
                            (register_base - Peripheral_Base) * 32 + 
                             bit_number * 4);
end reg_bit_to_address;
...
RCC_ENABLE   : Boolean with Atomic, size=>32;
for RCC_ENABLE'Address use reg_bit_to_address (RCC_ENABLE_REGISTER_Base, RCCBit);
```

As the function call is evaluated when (immediately after) RCC_Enable is declared, its result is constant, at least until RCC_Enable goes out of scope.

However you may be better declaring `RCC_Enable_Register` as a record, one of whose components is a Boolean named `RCC_Enable` or simply `Enable` since it can be addressed as `RCC_Enable_Register.Enable`. There is standard syntax for defining the address, layout and size of each component within the record.

As qualified expressions like `RCC_Enable_Register.Enable` can get verbose, they can be simplified using "renames", e.g.

```
RCC_Enable   : Boolean renames RCC_Enable_Register.Enable;
```

which declares a shorthand form for the duration of the current scope. As it's just a renaming there is no execution penalty, of course, If you keep it local to where you use it, you don't have to search far to find its definition...

Comment: Ok, I think I got fooled between the constness and the staticness, and when I read the RM, I though the rules for staticness (doent's allow user defined sub programs) applied, I had not even tried a function. I didn't know you could spread a record all over the memory, I though they could only have holes, I'll investigate this possibility. Thanks

Comment: I think I understand your idea of a record, I don't think I'll do it. There is already a record for the packed RCC register bank, one register per bus, and one bit in the register per peripheral. I'm adding the reverse, one bit that you flip (atomically) on the peripheral and it enables the peripheral without you remembering (or scouring the doc) what bus it is plugged in.

Comment: Constness and staticness are C-isms and don't exactly apply to Ada. If you're coming from C you have some unlearning to do, (it felt like healing to me!) but when the Ada way feels simpler and more natural, you'll know you're getting there. Oh, and don't overlook possibilities like "renames" ... I'll put an example in the answer.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Ada does have a "static" concept, although it isn't like C++/Java; a static value is one the compiler can figure out at compile time.  Some constructs require static values.  And the OP is right that in places where a static value is required, you can't have user-defined subprograms.  But the `'Address` clause does _not_ require a static value for the address.  I think that may be what he was referring to.

Comment: @BrianDrummond "There is a standard syntax for defining the address, layout and size of each component within the record"--not really true with respect to "address".  You can specify the position of the component relative to the start of the record, and the size in bits, but you can't specify individual addresses for each component.

Comment: Quite right : I should have said, don't apply in the same way. Ada doesn't have "const" but certainly has "constant"!

Comment: In a sense you can specify the address of each component, by specifying their relative positions, and - separately - the address of the record. But you're right I didn't make that clear enough.

Comment: I don't "come" from anywhere, I have used more than 20 languages in my life. I guess In bit banding I could still use record, they would use a lot of memory address space (since every bit would take 8 bits), which would be unusual but doable, but I don't know yet if I'll do that, I think it's mostly useful for 1 bit fields (in the register space I mean, in memory space there is more to it).

Answer (score 2):

For fun I tried translating the mangled code I found [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/CHDJHIDF.html) into Ada, following @BrianDrummond’s idea.

The C code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BITBAND_SRAM_REF 0x20000000
#define BITBAND_SRAM_BASE 0x22000000
// Convert SRAM address
#define BITBAND_SRAM(a,b) \
  ((BITBAND_SRAM_BASE + (a-BITBAND_SRAM_REF)*32 + (b*4)))

#define BITBAND_PERI_REF 0x40000000
#define BITBAND_PERI_BASE 0x42000000
// Convert PERI address
#define BITBAND_PERI(a,b) \
  ((BITBAND_PERI_BASE + (a-BITBAND_PERI_REF)*32 + (b*4)))

#define MAILBOX 0x20004000
#define TIMER 0x40004000
// Mailbox bit 0
#define MBX_B0 *((volatile unsigned int *)(BITBAND_SRAM(MAILBOX,0)))
// Mailbox bit 7
#define MBX_B7 *((volatile unsigned int *)(BITBAND_SRAM(MAILBOX,7)))
// Timer bit 0
#define TIMER_B0 *((volatile unsigned char *)(BITBAND_PERI(TIMER,0)))
// Timer bit 7
#define TIMER_B7 *((volatile unsigned char *)(BITBAND_PERI(TIMER,7)))

int main(void){
    printf("%x\n", &MBX_B0);
    return 0;
}
```

and my (partial) Ada is

```
private with System.Storage_Elements;

package Bitbanding is

   MBX_B0 : Boolean with Atomic, Size => 32;

private

   subtype Bit_Number is Integer range 0 .. 15;

   --  Register is the address of the register we are interested in.
   --  Register_Base is the start of the memory mapped to registers.
   --  Bit is the bit number within the register.
   --  Alias_Base is the start of the memory area where each
   --    32-bit word is mapped to one bit of the actual registers.
   --  The result is the address to which Register/Bit_Number is mapped.
   function To_Address
     (Register      : Natural;
      Register_Base : Natural;
      Bit           : Bit_Number;
      Alias_Base    : Natural) return System.Address
     is (System.Storage_Elements.To_Address
           (System.Storage_Elements.Integer_Address
              (Alias_Base
                 + (Register - Register_Base) * 32
                 + Bit * 4)));

   --  These are the names in the ARM example; they are not good.
   BITBAND_SRAM_REF : constant := 16#2000_0000#;
   BITBAND_SRAM_BASE : constant := 16#2200_0000#;

   MAILBOX : constant := 16#2000_4000#;

   for MBX_B0'Address use To_Address (Register      => MAILBOX,
                                      Register_Base => BITBAND_SRAM_REF,
                                      Bit           => 0,
                                      Alias_Base    => BITBAND_SRAM_BASE);

end Bitbanding;
```

together with a test

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Bitbanding;
with System.Storage_Elements;
procedure Bitbanding_Test is
   package Address_IO
     is new Ada.Text_IO.Modular_IO (System.Storage_Elements.Integer_Address);
begin
   Address_IO.Put
     (System.Storage_Elements.To_Integer (Bitbanding.MBX_B0'Address),
      Base => 16);
   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
end Bitbanding_Test;
```

which gives the same numerical result (`16#22080000#`) as the C.

Comment: I should have used `System’To_Address`, as @Brian did, to allow the package to be preelaborable.

Comment: thanks. For now I'm sticking with the peripheral space bit banding, because I too green to tackle smart algorithms in a target that can barely blink leds and whose state can only painstakingly be explored with gdb.